# How paginate data in redis using nestjs, mongoDB

Tags: typescript, mongodb, redis, nestjs, prisma

hello everyone im working in backend project with nestJS, MongoDB, prisma, zod and redis.
i created a whole service of authentication system with refresh token based on passport and im creating other service to create posts for a blog, this is using cloudinary to store the files and return the links to store it in the DB.
[this is the service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ueoG.png)
My service is using dynamic routing to make pagination when the user retrive the data from db using query params, the problem is how can use this pagination to store it in the cache system, and for example if the user wants to bring the 10 posts of 1000 and then he wants to update the number 5 the cache it will return the old call not the new updated post.

```
  async findAllPosts(
    offset: number,
    limit: number,
  ): Promise<{ posts: Post[]; total: number } | []> {
    try {
      const limitsValues = [10, 20, 50];

      if (limitsValues.includes(limit) === false) {
        throw new CustomErrorException({
          errorCase: 'invalid_limit',
          errorType: 'Post',
          value: limit,
        });
      }
      const dataCache = await this.cache.get(`posts:${offset}:${limit}`);

      if (dataCache) return dataCache;

      const posts = await this.prisma.post.findMany({
        skip: offset * limit,
        take: limit,
        orderBy: {
          createdAt: 'desc',
        },
        include: {
          resources: true,
        },
      });

      const data = { posts, total: posts.length };

      console.log('from DB', data);

      await this.cache.cacheState<Post[]>({
        model: 'post',
        storeKey: `posts:${offset}:${limit}`,
        limit,
        offset,
      });

      return data || [];
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.message);
      if (e instanceof CustomErrorException) {
        throw e;
      } else {
        throw new CustomErrorException({
          errorCase: 'post_not_found',
          errorType: 'Post',
          value: e,
          prismaError: e as Prisma.PrismaClientKnownRequestError,
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

The things is i dont know which is the best way to handle this kind of situation, should i use CQRS to have two differents DB, one to read and the other to manipulate? or Should i set uniques keys but the problem its the users will create infinites keys and that not make sense to have a cache system.
This is my endpoint:

```
  @Get('/post')
  async findPostByQueries(
    @Query('q') q: string,
    @Query('offset') offset: string,
    @Query('limit') limit: string,
    @Res() res: Response,
  ) {
    let posts;
    const postOffset = offset ? parseInt(offset, 10) : 0;
    const postLimit = limit ? parseInt(limit, 10) : 10;

    if (q) {
      posts = await this.blogService.findPostByQuery(q, postOffset, postLimit);
      return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Post found successfully', data: posts });
    }

    posts = await this.blogService.findAllPosts(postOffset, postLimit);
    return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Posts found successfully', data: posts });
  }
```

I'm a person im still learning so im dont know how can i handle this arquitecture problem thanks for the help

I tried to store a pagination data  in a cache system and should to be a dynamic cache system to manage changes from db